# How to find sum of elements from given index interval (i, j) in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, arrays

Given an array. How can we find sum of elements in index interval `(i, j)` in constant time. You are allowed to use extra space.
Example:
A: 3  2  4  7  1  -2  8  0  -4  2  1  5  6  -1 
length = 14

```
int getsum(int* arr, int i, int j, int len);
// suppose int array "arr" is initialized here
int sum = getsum(arr, 2, 5, 14);
```

sum should be 10 in constant time.

Comment: Now do it in `O(log N)` if you can also change an element's value between queries :).

Comment: int getsum(int* arr, int i, int j, int len) { return 10; } ;)

Comment: @Matt - Your constant time version is extremely slow. It should be `#define getsum(arr, i, j, len) 10` for maximum efficiency.

Comment: @:IVlad Only if you give me `O(log N)` time every time an element's value is changed!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can spend O(n) time to "prepare" the auxiliary information, based on which you would be able calculate sums in O(1), you could easily do it.

Preparation (O(n)):

```
aux[0] = 0;
foreach i in (1..LENGTH) {
  aux[i] = aux[i-1] + arr[i];
}
```

Query (O(1)), `arr` is numerated from `1` to `LENGTH`:

```
sum(i,j) = aux[j] - aux[i-1];
```

I think it was the intent, because, otherwise, it's impossible: for any `length` to calculate `sum(0,length-1)`  you should have scanned the whole array; this takes linear time, at least.

Comment: I think it should be aux[j] - aux[i-1].

Comment: @Lluis, if we numerate the array from 1 (which is the case), then it should.

Comment: im trying to adapt this to work with a 2 dimensional array, but i cant figure out what to change, would you mind to enlighten me?

Comment: @DanielBo sure.  In one-dimensional situation, the interval has two bounding points, and we use "sum from beginning to here" recorded at each bound.  How many bounding points has an interval in a 2D case (rectangle), and what does the "sum from beginning to here" mean?

Answer (score 5):

It cannot be done in constant time unless you *store* the information.

You would have to do something like specially modify the array to store, for each index, the sum of all values between the start of the array and this index, then using subtraction on the range to get the difference in sums.

However, nothing in your code sample seems to allow this. The array is created by the user (and can change at any time) and you have no control over it.

Any algorithm that needs to scan a group of elements in a sequential unsorted list will be O(n).

Comment: Yes, it is, in the context of adding up less than 15 integers :-)

Comment: You don't need to store 105 integers for a 14-integer array.  You can get by with cumulative sums and subtraction.

Comment: @David, see para 3, I covered that (as did Pavel, in a much clearer fashion). But it's still not possible *unless you can control the array*. Otherwise you have to pre-compute the values every time the function is called, at which point you may as well not pre-compute at all.

Comment: @paxdiablo:  Perfectly understood, but why the second paragraph?  That's what attracted my eye.  Other than that, it's an excellent answer.

Comment: @David, that was my first thought and I often leave in brain-f*rts for prosperity :-) The third para was added in an edit later on when I had some more chance to think about it (it's 4am over here, I'm only up because the kids are having nightmares, so I may be a little tired). I'll get rid of it though now it's not that much different from Pavel's.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are absolutely fine for the question asked. I am just adding a point, if this question is changed a bit like:

```
Find the sum of the interval, if the array gets changed dynamically.
```

If array elements get changed, then we have to recompute whatever sum we have stored in the auxiliary array as mentioned in @`Pavel Shved`'s approach.
Recomputing is O(n) operation and hence we need to reduce the complexity down to O(nlogn) by making use of `Segment Tree`.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/

Answer (score 1):

There are three known algorithms for range based queries given [l,r]

1.Segment tree: total query time O(NlogN)
2.Fenwick tree: total query time O(NlogN)
3.Mo's algorithm(square root decomposition)

The first two algorithms can deal with modifications in the list/array given to you. The third algorithm or Mo's algorithm is an offline algorithm means all the queries need to be given to you prior. Modifications in the list/array are not allowed in this algorithm. For implementation, runtime and further reading of this algorithm you can check out this [Medium](https://medium.com/@harryjobz/range-based-query-ec052edbf326) blog. It explains with code. And a very few people actually know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

this question will solve O(n^2)time,O(n)space or O(n)time,O(n)space..

Now the best optimal solution in this case (i.e O(n)time,O(n))
suppose a[]={1,3,5,2,6,4,9} is given
if we create an array(sum[]) in which we kept the value of sum of 0 index to that particular index.like for array a[],sum array will be sum[]={1,4,9,11,17,21,30};like
{1,3+1,3+1+5......} this takes O(n)time and O(n) space..
when we give index then it directly fetch  from sum array it means add(i,j)=sum[j]-sum[i-1]; and this takes O(1) times and O(1) spaces...
so,this program takes O(n) time and O(N) spaces..

int sum[]=new int[l];

```
    sum[0]=a[0];
    System.out.print(cumsum[0]+" ");
   for(int i=1;i<l;i++)
   {
       sum[i]=sum[i-1]+a[i];
       System.out.print(sum[i]+" ");
   }
```

?*   this gives 1,4,9,11,17,21,30  and take O(n)time and O(n) spaces */

sum(i,j)=sum[j]-sum[i-1]/*this gives sum of indexes from i to j and take O(1)time and O(1) spaces*/

so,this program takes O(n) time and O(N) spaces..***emphasized text***